# Advanced Installer MSI - Only Writing to ProgramData when Running WPF App as Administrator

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, advanced-installer, programdata

I have a WPF App I am saving a configuration file in.

I am attempting to write to:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData (C:\ProgramData\My App)
```

However, when I run the App (non Adminstrator) it writes the file here:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\ProgramData\My App
```

When I run the App as Administrator, it correctly writes to ProgramData.

This way I can share the settings file across users. Is there a special way the installer needs to be run or configured?

Is there another suggested way to share a configuration file without having to run the App as Administrator?

I am using Advanced Installer.

Comment: This is also nothing to do with windows installer or advanced installer. The install can't magically bless a limited user to run an app as if the user has elevated privileges. The app needs an elevation manifest for that.

Comment: When running the Installer on another machine with the same permissions it does create the directory. Not sure what is different/unique about my machine. Just an FYI I don't have the issue with a ClickOnce installer.